# JADE: express/node variables/objects in jade inline javascript?

Tags: variables, node.js, inline, express, pug

i use inline javascript in my jade templates for generating a google map. my problem is: how can i pass variables/objects from the node/express controller into this inline javascript snippet?

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1):

app.js:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.jade', { title: 'My Site', variable: { javascript: 'object' } });
});
```

index.jade:

```
- var header = 'this is from an ' + variable.javascript;
h1= header
```

Comment: nope didn't fix it. but have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270832/jade-express-iterating-over-object-in-inline-js-code-client-side please. thank you!