# NodeJS, ExpressJS & Jade - passing model to knockout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, express

I'm trying to get my expressJS-Model to my .jade-template, but the way I can access the Model with JS on the client-machine.

The idea is simple:
I want to use the Model with Knockout - so I need to give the Model-Object as it is to the client.

If I do the obvious - *var t = #{customer}* - I ending up with the rendered output *var t = [object Object]* 
So how can I use the object on the client-side?

Thanks!

Comment: found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681821/passing-objects-to-client-in-node-express-jade

Answer (score 1):

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the object on the server, and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it on the client (will only work in IE >= 8, if you need to support older i3-browsers you could provide json-js from douglas crockford: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js