# Passing mongoose documents to view and use in script tag node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, pug, objectid

I have an app running in Node.js with Express, and I wanted to dinamically change options on select object with jquery. This is actually not a big problem, but I'm having troubles on using the res.render parameters (which are mongoose documents) in the script tag. I use them without any trouble on the html (jade actually), but in the script tag I get a problem with the ObjectId not being a String.

This is an extract of the code:
**On the backend:**

```
router.get("/new", function(req, res){
res.render("session/documentos/new", 
    {
        services: res.locals.services
    });
});
```

**On the view**

```
block content
div
    h1(class="text-center") New document
    form(id="newDoc" action="/session/documentos" method="POST")
        div(class="tab") Service:
            div(class="form-group") 
                select(class="form-control" name="svc" id="svc")
                    option(value="undefined" disabled selected) Choose one
                    for service in services
                        option(value=service._id)=service.name

script.
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var sessLenght = 0;
        var selectedSvc = #{services};
        $("#svc").change(function(){
            console.log("Service changed: " + selectedSvc);
        });
});
```

And this is the error I'm getting:
[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BusV6.png)

And in Sources:
[Source error on ObjectId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zEAk.png)

So I'm being able to use with no troubles the "services" collection of documents, but when trying to use them on the script tag I'm getting problems with the ObjectId element.

I was thinking that one soution would be to convert to string the ObjectId when querying the database, but I think there might be a cleaner solution to that. Which might be the best way to solve the issue?

Any thoughts appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Why have `selectedSvc` in the first place? The option's value is the `_id`, which is enough to find the service when the form is sent back to express. What is the point of your script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing objects to client in node + express + jade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681821/passing-objects-to-client-in-node-express-jade)

Comment: Hello Chris. Yes of course I could find the document in the backend with the id, the thing is that I want to populate the options inside a select html-object with the information inside the service document. I want to read the information inside the service document from the script to make changes in the view. I'll check the link, thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `var selectedSvc = #{services};`

to `var selectedSvc = !{services};`

or `var selectedSvc = !{JSON.stringify(services)};`

Comment: Tried all those already, always the same issue. I "read" the document information but always an error over ObjectId element

Comment: @Mahum Maybe try `services.toJSON()` or `services.toObject()`

Comment: didn´t work either. Any other thoughts? Don't get it why I'm being able to use the documents in the html but not in the script tag.