# How to pass variable from jade template file to a script file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm having trouble with a variable (config) declared in a jade template file (index.jade) that isn't passed to a javascript file, which then makes my javascript crash. Here is the file (views/index.jade):

```
h1 #{title}

script(src='./socket.io/socket.io.js')
script(type='text/javascript')
  var config = {};
  config.address = '#{address}';
  config.port = '#{port}';
script(src='./javascripts/app.js')
```

Here is a part of my app.js (server side):

```
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.set('address', 'localhost');
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    address: app.settings.address,
    port: app.settings.port
});
});

if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(app.settings.port);
  console.log("Server listening on port %d",
app.settings.port);
}

// Start my Socket.io app and pass in the socket
require('./socketapp').start(io.listen(app));
```

And here is a part of my javascript file that crashes (public/javascripts/app.js):

```
(function() {
        var socket = new io.Socket(config.address, {port: config.port, rememberTransport: false});
```

I'm running the site on development mode (NODE_ENV=development) on localhost (my own machine). I'm using node-inspector for debugging, which told me that the config variable is undefined in public/javascripts/app.js.

Any ideas?? Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExpressJS Pass variables to JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268951/expressjs-pass-variables-to-javascript)

Answer (score 188, accepted):

It's a *little* late but...

```
script.
  loginName="#{login}";
```

This is working fine in my script. In Express, I am doing this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render( 'index',  { layout:false, login: req.session.login } );
};
```

I guess the latest jade is different?

Merc.

edit: added "." after script to prevent Jade warning.

Comment: Yes I got this working also by wrapping the local variable in the template in quotes and the #{} indicator.

Comment: This answer is dangerous, lagginreflex's answer correctly encodes the string (newlines in the login name could allow code execution).

Comment: So the issue was only the single quotes while double are expected, right?

Comment: For me the issue was the dot. I had it at the end of the script block. With the dot after the "script" keyword it works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 114):

**[`#{}`](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html)** is for escaped [string interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) which automatically escapes the input and is thus more suitable for **plain strings** rather than JS objects:

```
script var data = #{JSON.stringify(data)}
```

```html
<script>var data = {&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;} </script>
```

**[`!{}`](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html)** is for [**unescaped** code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html) interpolation, which is more suitable for **objects**:

```
script var data = !{JSON.stringify(data)}
```

```html
<script>var data = {"foo":"bar"} </script>
```

**CAUTION**: **Unescaped code can be dangerous**. You must be sure to sanitize any user inputs to avoid cross-site scripting (XSS).

E.g.:

```js
{ foo: 'bar </script><script> alert("xss") //' }
```

will become:

```html
<script>var data = {"foo":"bar </script><script> alert("xss") //"}</script>
```

Possible solution: Use `.replace(/<\//g, '<\\/')`

```
script var data = !{JSON.stringify(data).replace(/<\//g, '<\\/')}
```

```html
<script>var data = {"foo":"bar<\/script><script>alert(\"xss\")//"}</script>
```

The idea is to prevent the attacker to:

1. Break out of the variable: `JSON.stringify` escapes the quotes
2. Break out of the script tag: if the variable contents (which you might not be able to control if comes from the database for ex.) has a `</script>` string, the replace statement will take care of it

https://github.com/pugjs/pug/blob/355d3dae/examples/dynamicscript.pug

Comment: Great answer, and it works for objects! Btw, is `JSON` a global object? It seemed to work without importing any other libraries. If so, what about browser support?

Comment: @chharvey [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) is a javascript language builtin (like Date or Math), all browsers support it.

Comment: @laggingreflex thanks. I know what JSON itself is, but I wasn't sure what the actual `JSON` object was.

Comment: if the JSON object is huge. JSON.stringify(data) blocks the eventloop and stringifies the data synchronously.  any solution to overcome this ?

Comment: @vardha There's [EXPERIMENTAL Async promise based then-Jade](https://github.com/pugjs/then-jade), I haven't tried it but might be worth checking out. But if the data is really that huge I would probably give it its own API route and [serve the json directly](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) and handle it with ajax or socket on the client. [Clustering](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) can always help mitigate the single eventloop issues. ([pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/) makes it easier)

Comment: Agreed this is the best answer, but I do not think this is the right place to escape potentially-dangerous strings. IMO it would be better to omit the `replace` call in this code, and treat this value just like any other input. JSON.stringify is guaranteed to produce valid javascript (or fail), and after you have this potentially-dangerous value in memory you can make sure to sanitize it as needed before use.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I was attempting to pass an object into a template via an express route (akin to OPs setup). Then I wanted to pass that object into a function I was calling via a script tag in a pug template. Though [lagginreflex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310031/1353809) got me close, I ended up with the following:

```
script.
    var data = JSON.parse('!{JSON.stringify(routeObj)}');
    funcName(data)
```

This ensured the object was passed in as expected, rather than needing to deserialise in the function. Also, the other answers seemed to work fine with primitives, but when arrays etc. were passed along with the object they were parsed as string values.

Answer (score 8):

If you're like me and you use this method of passing variables a lot, here's a write-less-code solution.

In your node.js route, pass the variables in an object called `window`, like this:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        window: {
            instance: instance
        }
    });
});
```

Then in your pug/jade layout file (just before the `block content`), you get them out like this:

```
if window
    each object, key in window
        script.
            window.!{key} = !{JSON.stringify(object)};
```

As my layout.pug file gets loaded with each pug file, I don't need to 'import' my variables over and over.

This way all variables/objects passed to `window` 'magically' end up in the real `window` object of your browser where you can use them in Reactjs, Angular, ... or vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 3):

See this question: [JADE + EXPRESS: Iterating over object in inline JS code (client-side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6270832/542576)

I'm having the same problem. Jade does not pass local variables in (or do any templating at all) to javascript scripts, it simply passes the entire block in as literal text. If you use the local variables 'address' and 'port' in your Jade file above the script tag they should show up.

Possible solutions are listed in the question I linked to above, but you can either:
  - pass every line in as unescaped text (!= at the beginning of every line), and simply put "-" before every line of javascript that uses a local variable, or:
  - Pass variables in through a dom element and access through JQuery (ugly)

Is there no better way? It seems the creators of Jade do not want multiline javascript support, as shown by this thread in GitHub: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/405

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I addressed this (using a MEAN derivative)

My variables:

```
{
  NODE_ENV : development,
  ...
  ui_varables {
     var1: one,
     var2: two
  }
}
```

First I had to make sure that the necessary config variables were being passed. MEAN uses the node nconf package, and by default is set up to limit which variables get passed from the environment. I had to remedy that:

**config/config.js:**

original:

```
nconf.argv()
  .env(['PORT', 'NODE_ENV', 'FORCE_DB_SYNC'] ) // Load only these environment variables
  .defaults({
  store: {
    NODE_ENV: 'development'
  }
});
```

after modifications:

```
nconf.argv()
  .env('__') // Load ALL environment variables
  // double-underscore replaces : as a way to denote hierarchy
  .defaults({
  store: {
    NODE_ENV: 'development'
  }
});
```

Now I can set my variables like this:

```
export ui_varables__var1=first-value
export ui_varables__var2=second-value
```

Note: I reset the "heirarchy indicator" to "__" (double underscore) because its default was ":", which makes variables more difficult to set from bash. See another post on this thread.

Now the jade part:
Next the values need to be rendered, so that javascript can pick them up on the client side. A straightforward way to write these values to the index file. Because this is a one-page app (angular), this page is always loaded first. I think ideally this should be a javascript include file (just to keep things clean), but this is good for a demo.

**app/controllers/index.js:**

```
'use strict';
var config = require('../../config/config');

exports.render = function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    user: req.user ? JSON.stringify(req.user) : "null",
    //new lines follow:
    config_defaults : {
       ui_defaults: JSON.stringify(config.configwriter_ui).replace(/<\//g, '<\\/')  //NOTE: the replace is xss prevention
    }
  });
};
```

**app/views/index.jade:**

```
extends layouts/default

block content
  section(ui-view)
    script(type="text/javascript").
    window.user = !{user};
    //new line here
    defaults = !{config_defaults.ui_defaults};
```

In my rendered html, this gives me a nice little script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.user = null;         
 defaults = {"var1":"first-value","var2:"second-value"};
</script>
```

From this point it's easy for angular to utilize the code.

Comment: This is a very long winded way of saying what the accepted answer already says. Moreover, mentioning MEAN, nconf etc are irrelevant. The question is about how to pass variables to the client, not about how you did your dev stack. Not downvoting though, since you still put in lots of effort in this answer.