# ExpressJS Pass variables to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am completely lost on this; I am using NodeJS to fetch a JSON and I need to pass the variable to my page and have JavaScript use the data.

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.render('testPage', {
        myVar: 'My Data'
    });
```

That is my Express code (very simple for testing purposes); now using JADE I want to gather this data which I know to render on the page is simply

```
p= myVar
```

But I need to be able to gather this data in JavaScript (if possible within a .js file) but for now just to display the variable in an Alert box I have tried

```
alert(#{myVar})
```

And many others if anyone can  help be much appreciated

Comment: I don't know much about Node.JS or express, but i think you should change your testPage template to include a <input type=hidden> with the value of myVar

Comment: but maybe Express has means to abstract us from that

Comment: If you're passing HTML use Jade, Mustache or some other template. If you passing data then use JSON and have your transport parse it in to an object if the response is Content-Type: application/json.

Comment: not really what I am asking here; I am wanting to pass a JADE View variable which would normally be

p= myVar

into a JavaScript variable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following:

```
alert('!{myVar}')
```

It's a good idea to JSON encode the data if is more than just a string.

```
alert('!{JSON.stringify(myVar)}')
```

Comment: This fixed my problem thank you for your help; in order to pass into a .js file however simply just needed to create the variable in the .jade file and then the .js recieves it thanks again

Answer (score 11):

As Timothy said:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> var myVar = #{JSON.stringify(myVar)}; </script>
```

This can also be done as follows in if you don't like to write HTML in Jade/Pug templates:

```
script
  var myVar = !{JSON.stringify(myVar)};
  var myVar2 = !{JSON.stringify(myVar2)};
```

Update: For Express 4 and Pug use `script.` instead of `script` so that it will be rendered as javascript instead of html.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Javascript (and V8) has a built in function to render JSON from a object, and JSON happens to be syntactially compatible with Javascript.

So the easiest way to do what your trying to do would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript>var myVar = #{JSON.stringify(myVar)};</script>
```

And, yes, you can use HTML in a Jade template.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but I actually wrote a module (JShare) a few months ago to solve this exact problem. Check it out: https://npmjs.org/package/jshare

Answer (score -2):

You could leverage Now.js for this. It easily allows you to share variables client/server side real-time.

Check it out: http://www.nowjs.com/