# transfer data from jade to jquery and vice versa

Tags: jquery, node.js, pug, httpresponse

My `index.js` file:

```
res.render('index', {data:{'hello':'world'}});
```

my jade file:

```
p #{data}
script(src="/javascripts/app.js")
```

This prints the value json object.

now on my `app.js` file `console.log(data);` gives an error saying data is undefined.

How can I access the data which was passed from my index.js file in my javascript file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variable from jade template file to a script file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698534/how-to-pass-variable-from-jade-template-file-to-a-script-file)

Comment: So there the answer provided was loginName="#{login}"; which holds good when login is a string. like my examples. But I faced an actual problem when data is an actual object. Like JSON ojbect. I was not able to retrieve that object.

Comment: Peter Lyons, I have modified the question to reflect as such

Comment: Perhaps use `res.render('index', {data: JSON.stringify({'hello':'world'})});` in your index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `index.js` file:

```
res.render('index', {data:JSON.stringify({'hello':'world'})});
```

in your Jade Template:

```
script(type="text/javascript").
  var data = !{data};
```

That'll give you an object in the client-side JavaScript.