# How to pass variable in jade template using jade.compileFile

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using jade template to generate a html email, so I need to retrieve the html content by compiling the jade template. However I would need to pass in variable into the email content, so I have the following codes:

users.js:

```
var fn = jade.compileFile(__dirname + '/../templates/welcomeEmailTemplate.jade');
var html = fn({base_link:'http://something/'});
```

and then the welcomEmailTemplate.jade looks like:

```
img(src= !{base_link} + "image.jpg")
```

but this gives the error of:

```
Unexpected token }
```

on the above line in jade template file.

What should be the correct way to pass in variable in jade.compileFile?

Thanks!

Comment: `{base_link:{'http://something/'}` extra opening `{`

Comment: oh sorry that's a copy-paste error.. thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up two different syntax. You need to do either this:

```
img(src=base_link + "image.jpg")
```

or this

```
img(src="#{base_link}image.jpg")
```

Comment: img(src="!{base_link}image.jpg") doesn't seem to work? the rendered html shows <img src="!{base_link}image.jpg">) straight out.

Comment: Try `#{base_link}` that would work. [`#{}` is for escaped string, `!{}` for unescaped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698534/how-to-pass-variable-from-jade-template-file-to-a-script-file/28310031#28310031). I guess `!{}` doesn't work inside quotes