# Pass a value from response.render inside the script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Following is a `pug` snippet. I need to dynamically populate the `user` in `chatConfig` object.

```
 script.
  var chatConfig = {
    user : 'foo',
    pass : 'bar',
  }
```

From my express , I am rendering as

```
  resp.render('user/index', {username:req.user});
```

How do I pass the value of `req.user` to `user` key inside `script.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brmmmm is on the right track, but you need to get your JavaScript to use the variable as an object, not as a variable. You can stringify the variable to get it to work as a JavaScript object.

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    title Jade
    - var test = {prop1: "Hi there", prop2: "Another test"};
    script(type='text/javascript').
      var test2 = !{JSON.stringify(test)};
      console.log(test2, test2.prop1, typeof test2);
  body
    h1 Jade - template engine
    #container.col
      p I'm some Jade
```

[Live Example](http://codepen.io/shbelsky/pen/bqMeQp?editors=1001); check the browser console/Codepen console to see what the `console.log` statements output.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise it was an object. The variable name "username" mislead me lol . Sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should look like this:

```
script.
  var chatConfig = {
    user : '${username}',
    pass : 'bar',
  }
```

Comment: Sorry that should be '#{username}'

Comment: This also might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698534/how-to-pass-variable-from-jade-template-file-to-a-script-file