# How to use pug local variables in pug inline scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, view, locals

I have the following code (Chart.js piece):

```
datasets: [{
                  label: 'Hashes/s',
                  data: numbersList,
                  backgroundColor: [
                      'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                      'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                      'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                      'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                      'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                  ],
```

Now I'm passing this local like so from the main app:

```
require('../charter')((numbersList) => {
  res.render('index', {
    numbersList: numbersList
  })
})
```

Unfortunately it looks like it's only available to the top scope of the pug page. If I write `h1=hashesList` it will print out [1,2,3] (for example) but it seems the scope inside of pug scripts won't allow for this.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, then i believe you are looking for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698534/how-to-pass-variable-from-jade-template-file-to-a-script-file) ?

Answer (score 2):

In your pug template you need to use [unescaped interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) within your script as you stringify your data.

```
script.
  var numbersList = !{JSON.stringify(numbersList)};
```

This will output your variable as a browser-compatible JavaScript object.  Using the `#` symbol for escaped interpolation will not work here as it escapes quotes from `"` to `\\"`.