# How to pass variables to Pug's `script.` block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have this code in my `index.pug` file

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    script(src=`${source}`)
    script.
      for (var event of events){
        VClient.Event.subscribe(event, createDiv);
      }
```

And here is how I pass the variables from Express to pug.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var id = req.query.id || 23717;
    var source = `https://some.source.url/${id}.js`;
    res.render('index',
    {title: 'Preview Embed', source: source, events:["AD_START","AD_COMPLETE"]});
});
app.listen(5000);
```

Both `title` and `source` make it to the pug file. But not the `events`:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: events is not defined
```

How do I correctly pass the variable inside the `script.` block?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to basically render your variables in such a way that the end result gets interpolated as valid JS. It can be done with: `!{JSON.stringify(events)}`

```
for (var event of !{JSON.stringify(events)}) ...
```

which should expand to:

```
for (var event of ["AD_START","AD_COMPLETE"]) ...
```

Note the `!{}` which is for [unescaped interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped), as opposed to the more frequently used `#{}` which in this case wouldn't work as it would expand to something like `[&quot;...&quot;]` (i.e. escaped quotes)

**CAUTION**: **Unescaped code can be dangerous**. You must be sure to sanitize any user inputs to avoid cross-site scripting (XSS). See: [How to pass variable from jade template file to a script file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698534/how-to-pass-variable-from-jade-template-file-to-a-script-file/28310031#28310031)