# store nodejs object inside pug script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a few objects I need to render/store in my pug file for later use in client side JS scripts.

To store objects inside a script tag, I would use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49238358/4628115) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574113/how-to-pass-a-node-js-variable-to-the-inside-of-a-pug-script-tag):

NodeJS variable

```
const object = {
    "someKey": {
        "message":"this works"
    }
}
res.render("index", {object});
```

pug (somewhere in file - note the . after the script tag)

**note also I am using double quotes - you can use single quotes but I mention this for later**

```
script.
    var object = JSON.parse("!{JSON.stringify(object)}")
```

then somewhere in your javascript scripts

```
alert(object.someKey.message)
```

Read up more about Pug Interpolation [here](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html).

**Problem:**

For all my uses, the above example works fine. The problem comes in when I have an object with a single quote inside:

```
const object = {
    "someKey": {
        "message":"this doesn't work"
    }
}
```

Javascript doesn't like the fact that there is a single quote, as it sees the single quote as the start/end of a object key/value:

getting this from **Chrome console**
[image]

**Cause:**
[image]

Removing this single quote solves the problem. When hitting this point, the `JSON.parse()` function throws the exception and stops loading any and all JS, thus, no further functions work. *A work around is to put this at the very end of the page, but that doesn't solve the problem.*

**Question:**

How can I pass in an object from NodeJS to pug (as shown above) with single-quotes?

---

**Update**

MCVE of issue using standard NodeJS expresss boiler plate

https://github.com/cybex-dev/pug-single-quote-isse

**Setup Instructions:**

```
git clone https://github.com/cybex-dev/pug-single-quote-isse
npm install 
npm start
```

You should see expect to see some console output, I simply see:

[image]

and "error line"

[image]

Comment: @Graham nope - take a look at update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your working example with:

```
script.
    var object = JSON.parse("!{JSON.stringify(object)}")
```

But what works for me is this:

```
script.
    var object = !{JSON.stringify(object)};
    console.log(object.someKey.message);
```

Without double quotes: `var object = !{JSON.stringify(object)}`

Comment: Just remove the double quotes: `const stringified = !{JSON.stringify(object)}`

Comment: hmm, tried that before but somehow it didn't work. In any case, this solves my problem. Please post the 'remove quotes' as the solution. Thank you

Comment: Updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the other solution isn't clear.

**Simply:**

```
script.
  var object = !{JSON.stringify(object)};

//- don't forget a blank line to close your script block
```