# How send JSON data from pug to javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I send a JSON object from my mangoDB to the html page in this way:

```
router.get('/index', function (req, res, next) {
    GenoverseInstance.find({name: req.query.name}, function (err, instance) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            throw err;
        } else if (instance.length) {
            console.log('Object loaded');
            // object of the user
            console.log(instance[0]);
            res.render('index', {object: instance[0]});
        }
    });

});
```

I can use it in the html like this:

```
.containerCustom
  .head
    h1
      | #{object.name}
```

But I can not use it in my javascript which is included in the html page:
script.

```
alert(object.name);
```

How is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: I never used mangoDB, but it sounds delicious

Comment: From HTML to JavaScript?! Not sure what you mean.

Comment: make a separate route that just returns the json, then get it with client-side javascript.

Comment: Does the browser's console have anything to say?

Comment: Your question is: "How to access object properties in pug?"

Comment: This is the output of the browser's console:
ReferenceError: object is not defined
@JuanGonzálezSalinas

Comment: In fact, I succeed to use the object in pug but I can not use this object in the javascript which is included in the pug @ThomasKleßen

Comment: Then you have to make a call on JavaScript to pass the info, and don't forget to use [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp).

Comment: There is a very good explanation of what you are asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698534/how-to-pass-variable-from-jade-template-file-to-a-script-file#11985095).

Comment: @JuanGonzálezSalinas
I have to do a call from the router ?

Comment: Then you should store that info somewhere and retreive it.
Take the advice from @IsaacGodinez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the comments this link is very useful [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698534/how-to-pass-variable-from-jade-template-file-to-a-script-file), thanks to @IsaacGodinez. 
It's possible to use this line of code to get the entire object:

```
var data = !{JSON.stringify(object).replace(/<\//g, '<\\/')};
```

Or if you just want an element of the object:

```
var name = "#{object}";
```

Answer (score 3):

`object` is only defined in your Pug template and used to generate HTML that is then sent to the browser. After the HTML is generated, this `object` is consumed and disappears. It has nothing to do with the page's JS code.

If you want this data to be available in the JS code, then : from the generated page, make another (Ajax) request to your server, asking for this same data.

Answer (score 0):

this is because your response is saved in local scope and you don't pass that response to global scope where u can access it from outside.
I just make 1 snippet for you. Check it, i hope this will help you.
Also if you don't understand scopes i suggest you to go and read some articles, like [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) or [this](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-javascript-scope-1d4a74adcdf5). Also if you don't know what is asynchronous request read about them too.

```js
/* ############################### */

// So if you want to access response from your request you must save them or pass them
// This is one way to have access to your response outside by saving to global variable

// Creating variable where we will hold our response from request

// Global scope start here
var data = '';

function getResponse(res) {
  // Here is opened Local scope where u have no access from outside

  // and now here u have the response from your request
  console.log('function data', res);
  
  // you can do stuff here with that response
  data = res;
}

setTimeout(function() {
  var response = [1,2,3];
  // Now here we will save response to our data so we can access it from global scope
  // But remember that is async request
  data = response;
  
  console.log("local scope response ", response);

}, 1000);


setTimeout(function() {

  console.log("global scope data", data); // here data hold ur response data from your async request

}, 1100);



/* ############################### */
// This is another way to have access to your response outside by passing it to function
function getResponse(res) {
  // and now here u have the response from your request
  console.log('function data', res);
  
  // you can do stuff here with that response
  data = res;
}

setTimeout(function() {
  var response = [1,2,3];

  // other way pass response to your function and do what u want with that data
  getResponse(response);
  
  console.log("bracked scope response ", response);
}, 1000);
```