# Pass a variable in a javascript file to a pug file

Tags: javascript, pug

I have a javascript file "scripts.js" and I have a variable:

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

In my index.pug I tried this:

```
each n in myArray
  ul
    li n
```

but it doesn't work.

How can my variable in javascript is recognized in my index.pug?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass variable from jade template file to a script file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698534/how-to-pass-variable-from-jade-template-file-to-a-script-file)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, that is not the same because in this link is about how the variable from .pug is passed to the script file and I need the opposite, I need a variable declared in javascript to be recognized in the .pug.

Comment: U should be able to pass it in as answer suggests in .js file and then in pug it should be accessible.  `res.render( 'index',  { myArray:  ["a", "b", "c"] } );`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  My .js file is not a node file, it's only a vanilla javascript.  Can I use res.render in this case?

Comment: Never done myself. It looks like U can maybe do it as show on pug website Overview section: https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html. Seems u still need to compile the pug tho with node.

Comment: I'll review all your comments and the link sent.  Thanks.

Comment: The `myArray` variable exists in your browser while pug is generated on the server.  Without sending the variable back to the server using a form POST the two constructs just can't talk to each other the way I think you're expecting them to.

Comment: You can do this in js. Just use `forEach` and create `li` elements in it.