# What is the jade syntax to access variables in inline javascript?

Tags: angularjs, pug

All of my syntactic attempts have failed and the documentation on this particular case is hard to find, perhaps you know better.

```
.factsheet(ng-repeat="factsheet in factsheets)
    a(ng-href="{{factsheet.link}}", onclick="aFunction('click', {{factsheet.title}})")
```

`ng-href="{{factsheet.link}}",` works like a charm. `{{factsheet.title}}` is the variable which can't be accessed.

I've tried this

`factsheet.title`

and that

`#{factsheet.title}`

and this

`"{{factsheet.title}}"`

and other desperate attempts...

`'{{factsheet.title}}'`, `"#{{factsheet.title}}"`

Nothing works, although I can access the title attribute easily outside of the inline JS

```
h2 {{factsheet.title[currentLang]}} // no worries
```

Answer (score 0):

K, so after reading similar questions, especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270832/jade-express-iterating-over-object-in-inline-js-code-client-side), I figured this was just not the way to go and ended up using ng-click like so:

```
.factsheet(ng-repeat="factsheet in factsheets)
    a(ng-href="{{factsheet.link}}", ng-click="aFunction('click', factsheet.title)")
```

Less inline JS is always a good thing anyway!